# How can I use Spring Session in Websphere App Server?

Tags: spring-session

I'm wondering how can I user Spring Session in a Websphere App Server? Can I get 100% of Spring Session functionality? Does it have some limitations?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Session should work in Websphere in the same way it works with any other container.

The way Spring Session works is by leveraging a Filter that replaces the servlet Filter implementation. You can read more about it in [the reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/#httpsession-how).

I'm guessing you will need to configure the filter in the web.xml. If that is the case you can take a look at the [HttpSession XML](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/#samples) example.

One thing to keep in mind is that Spring Session does not currently support HttpSessionListener implementations. This is typically not a problem, but I wanted to make this explicit. If you have a need for this, you can vote for the feature / [track it here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/4).